# Pynput while not using text field

Tags: python, pynput

Im trying to make a simple code to crouch when I run it. this is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import keyboard as key
 
keyboard = Controller()
 
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(30):
    keyboard.press("c")
    keyboard.release('c') 
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: What's your problem?it runs well on my device.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA If Im in-game(CS:GO) and run it the character wont crouch

Comment: Pynput maybe couldn't do well in Game.